# ant build failes on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

When I start the Jenkins build, on arriving on ant-build-step the build is canceled immediately with the following stack:

```
...
[PROJECT] $ cmd.exe /C "D:\jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation\Ant\bin\ant.bat -file build-jenkins.xml -Djenkins.result.dir=${JENKINS.WORKSPACES}/Results "-Dbranch=*/develop" -Djenkins.result.dir=C:/Tools/Jenkins/Results -Djenkins.workspace.dir=C:\Tools\Jenkins\Project-SNAPSHOT\workspace/PRO_56/PRO/java/Project -Dproject.path=C:\Tools\Jenkins\Project-SNAPSHOT\workspace clean.compile.jar.server.snapshot -v && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
...
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I get no debug messages, nothing.
I've got other project with a similar/equal config which work. I think it could be a incompatibility of my plugins.

Has anyone experienced this bug before?

Comment: In my view this is not a problem with Jenkins but with ANT, do the same script work if started manually from the same path? About the build is canceled immediately, can you check the build config if there is any flag on "delete the workspace"?

Comment: Thank you, I started ant manually and got a minor.major-version conflict. So I checked the versions. Jenkins is using ant 1.10 and I'm trying to build a project in java 1.6. Ant 1.10 needs a JDK/JRE with java 1.8...

Comment: I have now set the JAVA_HOME correctly and choosen ant 1.9. Now I can build manually. In Jenkins still no success.

Comment: Okay, check the Jenkins Ant and Java version, mainly in the Jenkins configuration Tab you got to check ANT path and see if it's the same one, then you have to check if there is any variable that override the JAVA version in Jenkins or in the job itself.. let me know

Comment: I found the problem in the java-options I had set `-Xmx1024M
-Xms1024m`. The a small **m** the ant build starts. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a big **M** in the java options of the ant-build-step.
Here no **m** for Megabit und **M** für Megabyte.

`-Xmx1024M
-Xms1024m`